# Terraform Topic resource already exists in across projects? How to handle this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

How to deal with resources existing in multiple projects. In this case I have 2 TF projects and have a shared topic in google pubsub. Following the [google provider docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/pubsub_subscription.html) I created this configuration in the subscriber project. But it gives me a resource already exists error.

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "item_edited" {
  project = "listing-dev"
  name    = "item_edited"
}
```

So this resource already exits in some other project but following the guides I created it our own project as well.

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "item_edited" {
  name    = "item_edited_subscription"
  topic   = "${google_pubsub_topic.item_edited.id}"
  project = "${module.offer-dev.gcp_project_id}"
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* google_pubsub_topic.item_edited: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_pubsub_topic.item_edited: googleapi: Error 409: Resource already exists in the project (resource=item_edited)., alreadyExists
```

Answer (score 1):

Topic's name should have this format:

```
projects/<your_project>/topics/<your_topic_name>
```

For more information, you could check the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#pubsub-create-topic-protocol) and/or try the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/pubsub/v1/pubsub.projects.topics.create).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the correct answer is we need to use variables to explicitly define dependency in terraform config.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html

**By studying the resource attributes used in interpolation expressions, Terraform can automatically infer when one resource depends on another**